# How can I move the "ul" block of navbar to the right without affecting the toggle button functionality of responsiveness in the navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap NavBar ..

When trying to **move** the `ul` block to the right it disables the toggle button responsiveness ...

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand nav-text text-white" href="#">Rehan's Thoughts</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white disabled">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (shortest code necessary to replicate issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `w-100`(`width: 100%;`) to your `ul` element and also add `justify-content-end` or (`justify-content: right;`)

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand nav-text text-white" href="#">Rehan's Thoughts</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-end">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white disabled">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```